# XML column list specific value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, xml

I have an xml column that looks like this:

```
<document>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>Michael Burry</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>CDO</string>
        </value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>Adam Smith</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>£20</string>
        </value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>World Cup 2018</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>football</string>
        </value>
      </item>......
```

Instead of listing the entire contents of the column, I want to instead list only the value of `<string>football</string>` when the first value is `<string>World Cup 2018</string>`.

Using `value('(/document/item/key/string)[7]', 'nvarchar(max)')` is not suitable as "World Cup 2018" can appear anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a single value then you can just use the `value` method of the XML datatype with a little bit of XPath that translates to:

> Get me the first value of ...key/string which has a sibling element of
>   ...value/string under the same item element with the value "football"

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, yourXML XML )

INSERT INTO @yourTable ( yourXML )
SELECT 
'<document>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>Michael Burry</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>CDO</string>
        </value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>Adam Smith</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>£20</string>
        </value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key>
          <string>World Cup 2018</string>
        </key>
        <value>
          <string>football</string>
        </value>
      </item>......  
</document>'


SELECT *, yt.yourXML.value('(document/item[key/string[.="World Cup 2018"]]/value/string/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') result
FROM @yourTable yt
```

Comment: I have been able to get your solution working for me, however what I asked for was "I want to instead list only the value of <string>football</string> when the first value is <string>World Cup 2018</string>" The change I just described gives me what i wanted

Comment: I guess if you edit your answer I can give you the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your request.
The key is

```
where
     x.u.exist('key/string[text()="World Cup 2018"]') = 1
```

Here is the select :

```
 select
    x.u.value('(key/string/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as myKey
    ,x.u.value('(value/string/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as myValue
 from @xml_Text.nodes('document/item') as x(u)
 where
     x.u.exist('key/string[text()="World Cup 2018"]') = 1
```

output:

```
myKey           myValue
World Cup 2018  football
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3275565fbe737e70bc272c85170838ae)

or old way:

```
SELECT
       a.myKey ,a.myValue
 from
 (
 select
    x.u.value('(key/string/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as myKey
    ,x.u.value('(value/string/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as myValue
 from @xml_Text.nodes('document/item') as x(u) 
 )a
 where a.myKey = 'World Cup 2018'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I can't get this to work. The ```from @xml_Text.nodes('document/item') as x(u)``` part has a syntax error when I replace ```@xml_Text``` with my column name